# French poems about French grammar

Tags: poésie

In English, there are various humorous poems about grammar and spelling. In order to humor, or perhaps annoy, a poetry-focussed French teacher at my daughter's college, I wonder if there are any famous examples of this species in French?

Comment: I never heard about such entire *poems*, only… aphorisms, maybe. Could you give (an) example(s) in English?

Comment: A friend supplied http://www.jepoeme.com/forum/poeme-amour/Grammaire/343321/1.html#message4822078 and http://cartabletrecre.e-monsite.com/pages/content/themes-poesies/poesies-sur-la-grammaire.html

Comment: @bmargulies It would be worth an answer to me... (+1)

Comment: Les liens ne marchent plus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je propose la très jolie **[Harmonie imitative de la langue française](http://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/L%E2%80%99Harmonie_imitative_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise)**, d'Antoine-Pierre-Augustin de Piis comme un premier exemple en appelant d'autres...

*(l'ensemble est très volumineux, un tout petit extrait ici pour donner le ton)*

> A l’instant qu’on l’appelle arrivant plein d’audace,
>   Au Haut de l’alphabet l’A s’arroge sa place.
>   Allerte, agile, actif, avide d’apparat,
>   Tantôt, à tout hasard, il marche avec éclat ;
>
> [...]
>
> Balbutié bientôt par le Bambin débile,
>   Le B semble bondir sur sa bouche inhabile ;
>   D’abord il l’habitue au bonsoir, au bonjour ;
>   Les baisers, les bonbons sont brigués tour à tour ;